# Mouse freezes during installation of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, usb, mouse-pointer

I am installing Linux Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on a clean no OS computer. Came up with either TRY UBUNTU or INSTALL UBUNTU screen. The mouse cursor will not move. The computer is USB ONLY for mouse and keyboard and does not have connections for PS2 MOUSE and Keyboard.

Any suggestions on a work around or how to get past and install?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release of Ubuntu you are trying, if it was server or desktop, or if you validated your ISO after download & more importantly if you verified your write to media (20.04 will do this automatically, but we don't know your release).. Are you using a *live* installer?

Comment: it is 20.04 Desktop

Comment: This may not be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes, because this happens during installation, where REISUB will be pointless (that will cancel the installation) and restarting lightdm may not help either.

Comment: @irish515 Please edit your question to add information about your hardware (including graphics card, if any)